# memory usage by objects in common lisp

Tags: memory-management, common-lisp, clos

Is there a way to find out how much memory is used by an instance of a class or basic data types in general?

I have a toy webframework in cl that creates and manages web pages with instances of classes that represent the html tags and their properties, and as they are supposed to make an html page, they have children in a slot called children. so I was thinking how much a user's session will cost the server if I take this approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, there is nothing like this for arbitrary objects in the standard, but there are implementation-dependent solutions, like `ccl:object-direct-size` in CCL:

```
CL-USER> (object-direct-size "foo")
16
```

However, be aware that whether these do what you want depends on what you mean by "size", since those functions usually don't include the size of the components the object references. You can also run the GC, initialize a few objects and [compare](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Variable_size/Get#Common_Lisp) [`room`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_room.htm)'s [output](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Variable_size/Get#Common_Lisp) before and afterwards.

Also, note that [`time`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_time.htm) usually includes allocation information:

```
CL-USER> (time (length (make-array 100000)))
(LENGTH (MAKE-ARRAY 100000))
took 0 milliseconds (0.000 seconds) to run.
During that period, and with 2 available CPU cores,
     0 milliseconds (0.000 seconds) were spent in user mode
     0 milliseconds (0.000 seconds) were spent in system mode
 400,040 bytes of memory allocated.
100000
```

---

Maybe you could try something like this (untested, really just a quick hack):

```
(defmethod size ((object standard-object))
  (let ((size (ccl:object-direct-size object)))
    (dolist (slot (mapcar #'ccl:slot-definition-name
                          (ccl:class-slots (class-of object))))
      (when (slot-boundp object slot)
        (incf size (size (slot-value object slot)))))
    size))

(defmethod size ((list list))
  (reduce (lambda (acc object) (+ acc (size object)))
          list
          :initial-value (ccl:object-direct-size list)))

(defmethod size (object)
  (ccl:object-direct-size object))
```

For example:

```
CL-USER> (defclass foo ()
           ((child :accessor child :initarg :child)))
#<STANDARD-CLASS FOO>
CL-USER> (defclass bar (foo)
           ((child2 :accessor child2 :initarg :child2)))
#<STANDARD-CLASS BAR>
CL-USER> (size '())
0
CL-USER> (size "foo")
16
CL-USER> (size '("foo" "bar"))
40
CL-USER> (size (make-instance 'foo))
16
CL-USER> (size (make-instance 'foo :child '("foo" "bar" "baz")))
72
CL-USER> (size (make-instance
                'bar
                :child "foo"
                :child2 (make-instance 'foo :child (make-array 100))))
456
```

Comment: true, but the complete web page is somewhat hard to create without a request, and in the request there are many other things that get created for the user by hunchentoot. you know what I mean. I need some way to check this on the fly but your answer has opened the door thanks.

Comment: I wonder if it's wise to have classes for html tags and instances for each tag. You might be overdoing the "object oriented" thingy for probably no reason.

Comment: @SebastiánBenítez maybe, but i'm making good use of it, this allows me to full access to the page elements and defining my own kinds of tags  that i insert in the tag tree easily. so far it seems a page like [admin](http://lisper.ir/admin/) (no user pass needed if u wanna see what it does) costs me 1.3 mb. you can see where i have used such constructs if you look at the page source. of course this is possible in two ways, persistent pages and single create and render pages that will be gc-ed afterwards. persis is used when the page is too complex to manage without states, like the one above.

Comment: @danlei the main reason i didn't use (time ...) is that i assume it will report the conses during the run, but some of that mem will be gc-ed after the function has finished right?

Comment: Yes. I added a little (untested and not thought-through) example snippet – does that help?

Comment: @danlei yes it does but im using sbcl so i will need to dig into sbcl packages to find something like object-direct-size, but thanks for your time and effort

Comment: IMO, 1.3MB to generate a page is too much. It may be OK for a client to use that much memory to hold the DOM (and even more), but for a server... Perhaps you should be using a lighter approach, a more ajaxified design, with the server only doing server stuff.

Comment: @SebastiánBenítez i'm thinking about pushing the DOM to mysql and retrieving it when needed, this way it will free the memory, and i will still be able to use things like continuations. but serializing continuations is another story...

Answer (score 6):

In Common Lisp the CLOS objects usually are a collection of slots. Typically these slots might be internally stored in some kind of vector. CLOS slots typically will contain either a pointer to some data object or, for a few primitive datatypes, may include the data itself. These primitive data types have to fit into a memory word: examples are fixnums and characters. Common Lisp implementations typically don't inline more complex data structures into a slot. For example a slot could be declared to contain a vector of fixnums. Implementations would not allocate this vector inside the CLOS object. The CLOS object will point to a vector object.

The CLOS object itself should occupy then: number of slots * word size + overhead.

Let's assume a word is 4 bytes long, 32bit.

This might be the size for a CLOS object with ten slots:

```
10 slots * 4 bytes + 8 bytes = 48 bytes
```

Now imagine that each slot of a CLOS object points to a different string and each string is 100 bytes long.

Example from above:

```
1 CLOS object + 10 strings each 100 bytes.

48 bytes + 10 * 100 = 1048 bytes
```

Now imagine that each of the slot points to the same string:

```
1 CLOS object + 1 string of 100 bytes.

48 bytes + 100 bytes = 148 bytes
```

To calculate the size of a CLOS object you could either:

- just count the size of the CLOS object itself. That's easy.
- somehow calculate a graph of objects with are reachable from the object, determine the unique memory objects (minus direct allocated primitive objects) and sum all memory sizes of those.

Comment: I need to read this a few times before I can digest it, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

I also have web framework in cl, also was struggling with same sessions problem and here is what universe sent to me https://people.gnome.org/~xan/memory.lisp
It seems to work in sbcl

```
(memory::dump-memory (weblocks::active-sessions))
Total memory used: 99.785706 MB
```

Comment: It seems like it does not work with latest sbcl (1.5.3): `Symbol "LAYOUT-N-UNTAGGED-SLOTS" not found in the SB-KERNEL package.`